# wallpaper app with admob and push notification - got errors

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.1] G:\gradle-4.4.1\bin\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\OneSignal-3.8.1.aar\4992f150d9197af17fab12064aa2676a\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.onesignal" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: lol ? the error is itself  telling how you to resolve it....i think its explanation is better than ...any answer that can be posted!!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states you can either bump your minSdk to 15 or use and older version of OneSignal that has minSdk set to 14